# JPA PESSIMISTIC_WRITE usage in simultaneous reads flow

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am facing a situation where this is the flow

```
Time T0: Transaction 1 -> Read integer from DB 
Time T1: Transaction 2 -> Read integer from DB 
Time T2: Transaction 1 -> Increment, Write and Commit to DB 
Time T3: Transaction 2 -> Increment, Write and Commit to DB
```

Now this flow causes an incorrect increment because both transactions read the same integer value.

So does a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock in JPA implementations (Hibernate is the one I'm most interested in) protect against this flow ?

Also does this flow fall under any of the categories of dirty read, non repeatable read or a phantom read ?  
Seems to me like it doesn't because

1. Transaction 2 read the data before Transaction 1 wrote(modified) it hence its not a dirty read
2. Multiple reads aren't happening in a transaction here, hence not a case of non-repeatable reads or phantom reads

Comment: 'Multiple reads aren't happening' - the point is, if transaction B decided to read the integer *again* at T3, it would see a different value than at T1. Repeatable read is all about *guarantees*. Think of *repeatable read* this way: once a transaction reads a row, it cannot change 'behind the scenes'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that T1 and T2 are executed in different threads. It would be complicated to do that using JPA, but it is not impossible.

You have to read the integer in both Transactions T1 and T2 using "pessimistic write lock". Doing so, T2 is delayed until T1 is completed and the incremented value will be read.

The category is "non repeatable read". A second reading of T2, after the incremented value is saved in T1, might return the new value.
But... there are only few DBMS left where this is the case, since most DBMS like Oracle, MySQL, Postgres provide MVCC and therefore normally make sure that changes in other transactions are delayed until the first ist completed.

But in other DBMS, if you are using isolation level "repeatable read", a record always gets locked during reading to make sure, that it cannot be changed. Therefore T2 would deliver the integer not before T1 is completed. But be aware, that in MVCC-DBMS "repeatable read" can be achieved without locks, so that isolation level would not help then.